# Difference Between Python2, Python3, PyPy2, PyPy3

Tags: python, version, pypy

I am just wondering what the difference is between Python2, Python3, PyPy2, PyPy3 is.
I already understand that Python3 is the latest version of python, however I have no clue as to what PyPy2 and PyPy3 are, apart from the fact that some syntax is different. Thanks.

Comment: PyPy2 follows the syntax of Python2, PyPy3 follows the syntax of Python3. Any deviation in syntax is  a bug and should be reported to the issue tracker at https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/pypy/-/issues. You can read more aboout PyPy at their website https://pypy.org

Answer (score 3):

Python is the language - Python 2 and Python 3 are different major versions.

PyPy is an *implementation* of that language - it happens to be implemented in Python itself. This is in contrast to something like CPython (the de-facto "standard" implementation), which is written in C instead. PyPy 2 and PyPy 3 are implmentations of Python 2 and 3, respectively.